# Users registration in php: how to delete users that have not completed activation

Tags: php, email, registration, activation

I am going to write user registration in php and don't want to use any framework. Usually it looks like this:

1. User fills a registration form.
2. My app send an email to user's email address.
3. User complete registration by clicking link in email.

In first step i add user information into a special database table that stores inactivated users.
In third step i move user from that table into the table for activated users.

I have a few question:

1. Is this logic good? If not what is the common practice?
2. How and when i can to delete user from the first table if hi have not passed activation?
3. Are there lightweight libraries (not frameworks) for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of creating different table for activated and inactivated user. Just create a colum as `activate` and keep value as Activated =1/true and NotActivated=0/false

Comment: User will only activate his/her account by clicking on link given in mail. After activation user asked to login and after login ask user to complete registration

Comment: You can also add to step 1 of registration. Enable user to sign up using social media account.

Comment: Thank you Rohan. I agree with your comments but the main question for me was question 2) May be i should use php sessions mechanism for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of using php session mechanism to delete the data from db,"as you said in comment"

You can delete the data when you want. May be in 24 hours or 7 days or 1 month. May be it is depend upon traffic you will obtain.

But as soon as user registers store the time in `reg_time` column. By which during deletion the comparison will done with `reg_time`.

if you want to delete after 24 hours then

```
delete from ACCOUNT_TBL_DETAIL
where usrActivated=0 AND regTime <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

After 7 days

```
delete from ACCOUNT_TBL_DETAIL
where usrActivated=0 AND regTime <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

To schedule SQL script

```
CREATE EVENT delete_event
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO BEGIN
      DELETE messages WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END;
```

this is a simple cron script

Comment: I am new in php development. Which tool is commonly used for scheduling actions? Is it cron?

Comment: Yes the most common way to schedule things in php are cron jobs

Answer (score 2):

1. Normally this is one of the two ways to do it. The first one is storing a boolean if the user is activated. The second one is your way. With the second one having the advantage of keeping them separate for better management of those users.
2. You can just delete them from the table. The time depends on what your project requires but a relative good value would be one day
3. I don't think there are any libraries specific for the registration only part. But there're a lot of full-blown security libraries that incorporate this

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Should i use php sessions for temporary storing users instead of using db? This thought visited me right after questioning)

Comment: No, because sessions are tied to specific browsers. If they would activate their account from another browser than it wouldn't work